# Material derivative of a material vector field

Tags: derivatives, fluid-dynamics

> On page 12 of [*An Introduction to Theoretical Fluid Dynamics*](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/childres/fluidsbook.pdf), following the introduction of a material vector field $v_i(\mathbf a,t)=J_{ij}(\mathbf a,t)V_j(\mathbf a)$ the author wrote:
>
> $$
>     \frac{\mathrm D \mathbf v}{\mathrm D t}
>     =
>     \left. \frac{\partial \mathbf v}{\partial t} \right| _ {\mathbf x}
>   + \mathbf u \cdot \nabla \mathbf v
>   - \mathbf v \cdot \nabla \mathbf u
>     \equiv
>     v_t+\mathcal L_{\mathbf u} \mathbf v
>     = 0
> $$

**Question:** Shouldn't the material derivative of $\mathbf v$ be the following? Where is the "extra" term with the negative sign from?

$$
    \frac{\mathrm D \mathbf v}{\mathrm D t}
    =
    \left. \frac{\partial \mathbf v}{\partial t} \right| _ {\mathbf x}
  + \mathbf u \cdot \nabla \mathbf v
$$

**Update:** I believe it has something to do with Eqn. (1.22) which states that

$$
    \left. \frac{\partial \mathbf v}{\partial t} \right |_{\mathbf a} =
    \mathbf v\cdot\nabla\mathbf u
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some clarity the author has made the following calculation (I will explicitly give the variables that $\mathbf{v}$ depends on in each equation to avoid confusion)
$$\dfrac{\mathbf{Dv}}{\mathbf{D}t} = \dfrac{\text{d}\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}(t),t)}{\text{d}t}= \dfrac{\text{d}\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{a},t)}{\text{d}t} = \dfrac{\partial\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{a},t)}{\partial t}\tag{1}$$
But since $\mathbf{v}$ is a material vector field it satisfies the following differential equation
$$\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{a},t)}{\partial t} = \mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla \mathbf{u}\tag{2}$$
By definition the material derivative (as it is really just a total derivative) is 
$$\dfrac{\mathbf{Dv}}{\mathbf{D}t} = \dfrac{\partial\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}(t),t)}{\partial t} + \mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}(t),t)\tag{3}$$
Then equation $(1)$ implies that 
$$\dfrac{\mathbf{Dv}}{\mathbf{D}t}-\left.\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial t}\right\vert_{\mathbf{a}} = 0$$
Rewriting this using equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ we arrive at 
$$\left.\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial t}\right\vert_{\mathbf{x}} + \mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla \mathbf{u}=0$$
The fancy expression you see in this equation has a name, the lie derivative 
$$\mathcal{L}_\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla \mathbf{u}$$
So finally we have the result
$$\mathbf{v}_t + \mathcal{L}_\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

My confusion has been resolved. I was assuming that the material derivative of $\mathbf v$ should be equal to 0.

However, by definition,

$$\frac{\mathbf D \mathbf v}{\mathbf D t} = \left. \frac{\partial \mathbf v}{\partial t} \right|_{\mathbf a}$$

Therefore Eqn. (1.23) holds.

Comment: what is the difference between an ordinary vector field and a material vector field ?

Comment: @gansub Well...  I recall that there's no difference.  As to the advention component, it's _not_ implied to be zero. I think that term is already contained within $\left. \frac{\partial \mathbf v}{\partial t} \right|_{\mathbf a}$ because of how chain rules work. (The subscript is $\mathbf a$, not $\mathbf x$)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258632/material-derivative-lie-derivative-clarification-from-existing-answer